# Moles: Mole a ReadOnly Shared/Static Property

Tags: moles

How can I return a different value for MyList using Moles?

Given the following class:

```
Namespace Test

    Public Class MyTestClass

        Private Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Shared ReadOnly MyList As New List(Of String)({"SomeValue"})

    End Class

End NameSpace
```

I've tried to access the shared property from `Test.Moles.MMyTestClass` but `MMyTestClass` doesn't contain the member `MyList`. I also tried to add a behavior to return the value I want, but again, I'm not sure how to access the MyList from the test method.

Thanks!